# NSString stringWithUTF8String:jsonStr GET null

Tags: ios

```
const char* jsonStr = g_pLuaApplication->GetAppSceneAdapter()->GetModelList();
printf("jsonStr=%s\n", jsonStr);
NSString* nsStr = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:jsonStr];
NSLog(@"nsStr=%@", nsStr);
```

As above, the output is:

```
jsonStr={"Image":"\/var\/mobile\/Containers\/Data\/Application\/xxxx-xx-xx-xxx-xxx\/Documents\/ModelSnap\/170725_215831.png","nChecked":1,"Name":"\364\364"}
nsStr=(null)
```

The jsonStr is a json string from CJSON.encode. I want to convert it to a NSString. Why do I get null? How can I do?
Thank you

Comment: Use JSONEncoding.default

Answer (score 0):

Those slashes ("\") in "\364\364" are not escaped, thus your json string will be deemed invalid.

Comment: Thank you, I found that the name is not utf8 encoded.